# Creating lists in python that are dependent on previous elements

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am learning python and am working on list comprehension right now.  I am doing a problem that asks to generate a list of lists of n elements where the first element in each inner list represents its index, the next n-2 elements are random numbers between 1 and 10, and the last element is the sum of the previous n-2 elements where the value was over 5. For example a sample would be

```
[[0, 5, 10, 3, 10], [1, 7, 3, 7, 14], [2, 2, 9, 5, 9]]
```

The code I used to generate the output above was

```
import random
SUM = 0
def genRandNum():
    global SUM
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    if(x > 3):
        SUM = SUM + x
    return x

def finalEle():
    global SUM
    ret = SUM
    SUM = 0
    return ret

INNER_LIST_SIZE = 5
OUTER_LIST_SIZE = 3
li = [[y if x == 0
         else finalEle()if x == INNER_LIST_SIZE - 1
         else genRandNum()
         for x in range(INNER_LIST_SIZE)] for y in range(OUTER_LIST_SIZE)]
print(li)
```

However, coming from a language like Java I am inclined to write my code like this below script:

```
import random
SUM = 0
THRESHOLD = 5
INNER_LIST_SIZE = 5
OUTER_LIST_SIZE = 3
li = []
for y in range(OUTER_LIST_SIZE):
    innerLi = []
    for x in range(INNER_LIST_SIZE):
        if x == 0:
            innerLi.append(y)
        elif x == INNER_LIST_SIZE-1:
            innerLi.append(SUM)
        else:
            rand = random.randint(1,10)
            innerLi.append(rand)
            if rand > THRESHOLD:
                SUM += rand
    li.append(innerLi)
    SUM = 0
print(li)
```

Which one of these solutions looks like a better way to solve the problem from a python perspective? Are either of them actually how I should be doing this problem, and if not what are the other python tools that I could use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions to generate the random numbers and to filter the random numbers to those greater than 5 for the sum.  It actually makes for very short code.

```
import random

def gen_randoms_and_sum(n):
    r_list = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(n)]
    return r + [sum(x for x in r_list if x>5)]


[[i, *gen_randoms_and_sum(3)] for i in range(3)]
# returns:
[[0, 9, 7, 3, 16], [1, 3, 5, 9, 9], [2, 3, 9, 2, 9]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this code without calling the sum function?  Im asking just because I believe that sum will make a pass through the entire list after r_list has been created so when the INNER_LIST_SIZE and OUTER_LIST_SIZE get larger it will take 2 times more time.  Is this an issue I should even worry about since they will both be O(INNER_LIST_SIZE * OUTER_LIST_SIZE)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to count iterations, and a list comprehension followed by a sum for the rest of the numbers:

```
import random
number_of_randoms_per_list = 5
number_of_lists = 3
my_list = []
for list_count in range(number_of_lists): # number of lists to make
    random_nums = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(number_of_randoms_per_list)]
    temp = [temp for temp in random_nums[-2:] if temp > 5]
    my_list.append([list_count, *random_nums[:], sum(temp)])
print(my_list)
```

Where

- `[random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(number_of_randoms_per_list)]` generates a bunch of random numbers (changed by `number_of_randoms_per_list`)
- `temp = [temp for temp in random_nums[-2:] if temp > 5]` uses an index [-2:] to only get the last couple of numbers from the previously made random number list (and implements a test so it will only append them if they're > 5)
- `my_list.append([list_count, *random_nums[:], sum(temp)])` combines all the information we've gathered and assembles it into a list (by unpacking our random numbers with the `*` operator!

Outputs:

```
[[0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 5, 8], [1, 8, 5, 4, 4, 3, 0], [2, 4, 3, 8, 6, 10, 16]]
```

Comment: I think the point is to have a dynamic number of random numbers in between.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid all of the helper functions, especially since they use `global` (not a good sign if it has to be used!).

```
from random import randint

INNER_LIST_SIZE = 5
OUTER_LIST_SIZE = 3
THRESHOLD = 5

li = [[*seq, sum(x for x in seq[1:] if x > THRESHOLD)] for seq in ([idx, *(randint(1, 10) for _ in range(INNER_LIST_SIZE - 2))] for idx in range(OUTER_LIST_SIZE))]
```

Prettified w/ comments:

```
li = [
    # append the sum at the end
    [*seq, sum(x for x in seq[1:] if x > THRESHOLD)]
    # iterate through a generator that generates sequences of [index] + [random ints]
    for seq in (
        # list with [index, randint1, randint2, randint3, ...]
        [idx, *(randint(1, 10) for _ in range(INNER_LIST_SIZE - 2))]
        for idx in range(OUTER_LIST_SIZE)
    )
]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess if they're asking you to use list comprehension for the exercise they want you to define the lists inline:

[List comprehensions Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

So much as your solutions might work, they would likely not be what the setter of the question is looking for.

```
def build_list(number_of_randoms=3, outer_list_size=3, threshold=5):

rands = [[random.randint(1, 10) for _x in range(number_of_randoms)] for _y in range(outer_list_size)]
return [[index] + [n for n in numbers] + [sum(x for x in numbers if x > threshold)] for index, numbers in enumerate(rands)]
```

I've written a fairly crude function above, but it should help give you an idea of what I think they're looking for.